# Is there an alternative to Auth / Acl component for CakePHP?

Tags: authentication, cakephp

It's just too complicated to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Auth for people who hate the Auth component" - http://github.com/felixge/cakephp-authsome

Answer (score 0):

Found one

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/obauth-simple-authentication